# QListWidget cannot add an item dynamically

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt application, I want to add a new item dynamically into a listview. Besides I also used Signal & Slot to transfer data between forms so I have created 2 following forms:

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void ReceivedData(QString item);

private slots:
    void on_btnAdd_clicked();

    void on_btnCancel_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    void SetUpListName();
};
```

**addform.h**

```
class AddForm : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AddForm(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AddForm();

signals:
    void SendData(QString item);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::AddForm *ui;
    MainWindow *main_window;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    SetUpListName();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::SetUpListName()
{
    // Add 5 new elements
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        QString item = "Item " + QString::number(i);
        ui->lwListItem->addItem(item);

    }
}

void MainWindow::on_btnAdd_clicked()
{
    // Open Add Form
    AddForm add;
    add.setModal(true);
    add.exec();
}

void MainWindow::on_btnCancel_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}

void MainWindow::ReceivedData(QString item)
{
    // Check to receive data
    qDebug() << "Item: " << item;

    // Add a new item to list items
    ui->lwListItem->addItem(item);
}
```

**addform.cpp**

```
AddForm::AddForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::AddForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    main_window = new MainWindow();
    connect(this, SIGNAL(SendData(QString)), main_window, SLOT(ReceivedData(QString)));

}

AddForm::~AddForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

void AddForm::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // Send data via Signal & Slot
    emit SendData(ui->txtName->text());
}

void AddForm::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
```

When I run the application, I got the data from **Add** form but the list view **doesn’t** add this item.

[image: Cannot add an item dynamically]

Does someone have any solutions?

Thanks!

***P/S:*** You can download my source code at [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/9djf6bazr8b18n3/Demo.rar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are connecting the signal to the wrong object's slot. In the constructor of `AddForm`, you are creating a new `MainWindow` and connecting the signal to it's slot which means that the signal does not reach your real `MainWindow`, and the `ReceivedData` slot is adding the item to the wrong `QListWidget`. What you should do is this:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnAdd_clicked()
{
    // Open Add Form
    AddForm add;
    connect(&add, SIGNAL(SendData(QString)), this, SLOT(ReceivedData(QString)));
    add.setModal(true);
    add.exec();
}
```

and remove the creation of a new `MainWindow` and corresponding `connect` call from the constructor of `AddForm`.